# Replace x-axis label from the plot of a MarkovChain object

Tags: r, plot, clickstream

Here is some code to generate a 0th order Markov Chain plot. I'd like to replace the plot's x-axis labels (c, d, h, i, o, p) with 45 degree rotated labels showing the first six months of the year. However, using `xaxt="n"` in the `plot` call doesn't seem to work. This code just writes over the existing labels, rather than replacing them. How can I replace the labels with the ones I want?

```
library(clickstream)
clickstreams <- c("User1,h,c,c,p,c,h,c,p,p,c,p,p,o",
                   "User2,i,c,i,c,c,c,d",
                   "User3,h,i,c,i,c,p,c,c,p,c,c,i,d",
                   "User4,c,c,p,c,d",
                   "User5,h,c,c,p,p,c,p,p,p,i,p,o",
                   "User6,i,h,c,c,p,p,c,p,c,d")
csf <- tempfile()
writeLines(clickstreams, csf)
cls <- readClickstreams(csf, header = TRUE)
mc <- fitMarkovChain(cls, order=0)
plot(mc, xaxt="n")
text(x=1:6, y=par()$usr[3], labels = month.name[1:6], srt=45, adj = c(1.1,1.1), xpd = TRUE, cex=.9)
```

[image: clickstream plot with wrong x-axis labels]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str(mc)` reveals the structure of the S4 object. Passing into `plot` just the xy-coordinates rather than the whole `"MarkovChain"` object recovers the `xaxt` option functionality. Using `with` makes this most convenient.

Moreover this allows us to use the implemented S4 `plot` method for signature `'MarkovChain'` of the `clickstream` package.

```
library(clickstream)
with(mc@transitions[[1]], plot(states, probability, xaxt="n"))
text(x=1:6, y=par()$usr[3], labels=month.name[1:6], srt=45, adj=rep(1.1, 2), xpd=TRUE, cex=.9)
```

***Result***

[image]

***Data***

```
library(clickstream)
mc <- new("MarkovChain", states = c("h", "c", "p", "o", "i", "d"), 
    order = 0, transitions = list(structure(list(states = structure(1:6, .Label = c("c", 
    "d", "h", "i", "o", "p"), class = "factor"), frequency = c(25L, 
    4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 17L), probability = c(0.416666666666667, 
    0.0666666666666667, 0.0833333333333333, 0.116666666666667, 
    0.0333333333333333, 0.283333333333333)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L))), lambda = 0, logLikelihood = -88.4241188515082, observations = 60, 
    start = structure(c(c = 0.166666666666667, h = 0.5, i = 0.333333333333333
    ), class = "table", .Dim = 3L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("c", "h", "i")), .Names = "")), end = structure(c(d = 0.666666666666667, 
    o = 0.333333333333333), class = "table", .Dim = 2L, .Dimnames = structure(list(
        c("d", "o")), .Names = "")), transientStates = c("c", 
    "h", "i", "p"), absorbingStates = c("d", "o"), absorbingProbabilities = structure(list(
        state = structure(1:4, .Label = c("c", "h", "i", "p"), class = "factor"), 
        d = c(0.792201957232916, 0.864224245314581, 0.903842865008182, 
        0.517925028202586), o = c(0.207798042767084, 0.13577575468542, 
        0.0961571349918185, 0.482074971797414)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(c = 1L, 
    h = 3L, i = 4L, p = 6L)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `plot.default` rather than `plot` exposes the graphics `plot` function, which allows the use of the `xaxt` function parameter to remove the existing x-axis labels. Since `plot.default` won't accept a MarkovChain object, the `x` and `y` values for the plot need to be extracted from the object.

```
plot.default(
   x=mc@transitions[[1]]$states, 
   y=mc@transitions[[1]]$probability,
   xaxt="n", 
   ann=FALSE, 
   pch="-", 
   cex=3
)

text(
    x = 1:6, 
    y = par()$usr[3], 
    labels = month.name[1:6], 
    srt = 45, 
    adj = c(1.1,1.1), 
    xpd = TRUE, 
    cex = .9
)
```

[image]

Comment: `with(mc@transitions[[1]], plot(states, probability, xaxt="n"))` would also work.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is better than mine as it uses the original styling for the clickstream plot function. If you want to submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done so, glad to help!